# Printing a magazine from InDesign - A4 to A3

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

Very much a newbie on InDesign. Working with a document set to be a magazine with the facing property enabled.

I would like to export to PDF (alternative welcome!) and then print it so that all I have to do is fold the pages for it to be readable.

The only way I can make this work currently is to

- Disable the facing property
- If I had 8 page (A4) document, I'd set printing properties to print 2 per page (having set page type as A3)
- Set the print property to print both sides
- Print pages 8,1,2,7,6,3,4,5

It's fairly manual - I was wondering if I was missing a trick? Using latest version of InDesign.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Document set in facing page reader spreads....

choose `File > Print Booklet...`